# OpenGL - Correct way to load multi faces

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

If I got a cube model for example (cube got 6 faces). how can I draw each face with vbo? do I need to call glDrawElements 6 times? or is there another function to draw all at once? Usually I draw it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < facesNum; i++)
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4 + i*4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)(i*4));
```

Is that the best way?

Comment: Are you targeting a specific OpenGL version? Depending on the minimum version it needs to work with, there are different options.

Comment: My version is Opengl 4.4. But I prefer opengl 4.

Comment: How are you currently storing the face data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Primitive Restart](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart) (OpenGL 3.1+) to restart a primitive such as a triangle fan while rendering, as if you started another `glDraw*` command.

Use `glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART)` to enable it, then `glPrimitiveRestartIndex(restartIndex)` to set an index (such as `0xFFFF`) to use to signal a restart. Then whenever OpenGL encounters the restart index, it will stop the currently drawn primitive and start another one.

This lets you draw multiple triangle strips, fans, line loops, or strips with one index buffer and draw command. Just add the restart index between each primitive's index data.

Comment: You could also mention `glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX)`, which is slightly more convenient, but was unfortunately only added in 4.3. On the other hand, it's the only option for primitive restart in ES 3.0. I think primitive restart is the best approach here. Exactly what I had in mind when I asked about the OpenGL version.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, what you would do is draw your object as `GL_TRIANGLES` instead of `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, which allows you to just draw all 12 triangles (6 faces * 2 triangles per face) with one call to `glDrawElements`.

To do this, you of course have to somewhat rearrange your Index Buffer, to include the information for the vertices of each triangle. This means you have to duplicate some indices, which should however not be a problem, as the point of the Index Buffer is precisely to be able to do this and not duplicate vertices.

Assuming your top face consists of the vertices index 0,1,2,3 in counterclockwise order,
you would change that part of the index buffer from `0,1,2,3` to `0,1,2,0,2,3` for example.

With this changed setup of the index buffer, all it should take would be a call to

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

(36 as we are drawing 12 triangles for the cube with 3 vertices each)

Comment: Cube is an example. I have many models with thousands of polygons. I can not change the indices one by one.

Comment: Apart from the method I suggested above, I do not believe there is a better way, so I would suggest that you modify the code that loads/generates your models to generate indices for triangles as opposed to triangle fans. To the best of my knowledge, this is the only method to draw everything with a single call to `glDrawElements`, and I have used to to draw a (generated) sphere mesh with thousands of vertices without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to call DrawElements once with a single VBO. There are alternatives such as IBO's, but I am going to provide an example for a VBO since that is what you requested. Ideally, you should store all the vertices in an array or std::vector holding Vertex objects. Put all of your cube face vertices in this array or std::vector. You do not need an array/vector for each face. You will want to keep the data tightly compact and avoid using the virtual keyword as it creates a non exposed pointer (vtptr) which adds to your class memory footprint. The reason you want to keep the data compact is for when you send it to OpenGL, it will expect step sizes. If you ever are in doubt of the memory footprint of a class, it never hurts to do a quick output with the sizeof( ClassName ) function.

Your vertex class would look something like as follows;

```
class Vertex {
public:
    ~Vertex() {}
    Vertex() {} 

    Vector3<float>          vertexPosition;
    Vector4<float>          vertexColor;
    Vector2<float>          vertexTextureCoords;
    Vector3<float>          vertexNormal;
    Vector3<float>          vertexTangent;
    Vector3<float>          vertexBitangent;
    Vector4<int>            vertexBoneIndexes;
    Vector4<float>          vertexBoneWeights;
};
```

Where all the vector classes are NON virtual and the only data members are the vector components.

Here are the steps I follow:

- Create a std::vector (or array) of vertex objects and populate the vertex data
- Generate the VBO with the appropriate OpenGL Calls (Here is an example from my engine). I use a singleton which has wrapper functions in order to be Graphics API agnostic. The parameters are in the exact same order OpenGL would expect them for their VBO generation functions.

  ```
  cbengine::CBRenderer * sharedRenderer = cbengine::CBRenderer::sharedCBRenderer();
  sharedRenderer->generateVBOBuffers( 1, &entityToCreate->m_VBOBufferID );
  sharedRenderer->bindVBOBuffer( entityToCreate->m_VBOBufferID );
  sharedRenderer->bufferDataForVBO( ( sizeof( cbengine::Vertex ) * entityToCreate-   >m_verts.size() ), &entityToCreate->m_verts.front() );
  ```
- In your render function make the following OpenGL Calls. This is why I advised keeping the data tightly compact earlier. OpenGL needs to know what type of data to expect, the size of the data type, and the offset from the start of the data.

  ```
  glEnableVertexAttribArray( m_vertexLocation );
  glVertexAttribPointer( m_vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( cbengine::Vertex ), (float*) offsetof( cbengine::Vertex, vertexPosition ) ); 

  glEnableVertexAttribArray( m_colorLocation );
  glVertexAttribPointer( m_colorLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( cbengine::Vertex ), (float*) offsetof( cbengine::Vertex, vertexColor ) );

  glEnableVertexAttribArray( m_diffuseTextureCoordLocation );
  glVertexAttribPointer( m_diffuseTextureCoordLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( cbengine::Vertex ), (float*) offsetof( cbengine::Vertex, vertexTextureCoords ) );

  glEnableVertexAttribArray( m_normalCoordLocation );
  glVertexAttribPointer( m_normalCoordLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( cbengine::Vertex ), (float*) offsetof( cbengine::Vertex, vertexNormal ) );

  glEnableVertexAttribArray( m_tangentLocation );
  glVertexAttribPointer( m_tangentLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( cbengine::Vertex ), (float*) offsetof( cbengine::Vertex, vertexTangent ) );

  glEnableVertexAttribArray( m_bitangentLocation );
  glVertexAttribPointer( m_bitangentLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( cbengine::Vertex ), (float*) offsetof( cbengine::Vertex, vertexBitangent ) );

  glEnableVertexAttribArray( m_boneIndexesLocation ); // Apparently GL_INT causes issues
  glVertexAttribPointer( m_boneIndexesLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( cbengine::Vertex ), (float*) offsetof( cbengine::Vertex, vertexBoneIndexes ) );

  glEnableVertexAttribArray( m_boneWeightsLocation );
  glVertexAttribPointer( m_boneWeightsLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof( cbengine::Vertex ), (float*) offsetof( cbengine::Vertex, vertexBoneWeights ) );
  ```
- Lastly, make a call to DrawArrays

  ```
  sharedRenderer->drawArrays( drawPrim, 0, verts.size() );
  ```

This is a very quick example of how to accomplish what you want. Other things to keep in mind are winding order for culling, enabling/disabling textures, and custom vertex attrib data you may want to send to your shaders. You may not want to include the Bone Weights and Bone Indexes vectors if your engine does not support skeletal animation.